# move_base managing goal

Tags: navigation, move-base, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can someone explain me how the local_planner receive the goal coordinates?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61591/move_base-managing-goal/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2013-04-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Algorithm of local planner  is based on global plan (is not based on the goal).

There is method in 'TrajectoryPlannerROS' [class](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/groovy-devel/base_local_planner/src/trajectory_planner_ros.cpp):

```
bool TrajectoryPlannerROS::setPlan(const std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& orig_global_plan)
```

Alex

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2013-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2015-01-21**:
Can I change this and make the local planner to follow my own trajectory?